# Energy estimation of an acoustic wave

Tags: waves, acoustics, poynting-vector

I have an issue with 2D acoustic wave field modelling.

In order to estimate the energy propagation direction of an acoustic wave I use Poynting vectors $S$ which can be described by

$$
\vec{S} = - \dot{p} \nabla p
$$

where $p$ is the pressure field, $\dot{p}$ represents the time derivative of the pressure field and $\nabla p$ represents the spatial gradient of the pressure field.
Taking the absolute value of $\vec{S}$ it is possible to estimate the energy of the wave field at a certain grid point at a certain time step.

Since $\nabla p$ can become very small, the Poynting vector field may become quite noisy for complicated wave fields. As a result, I want to reject Poynting vectors, that are too small by comparing the actual energy of the wave field with $|\vec{S}|$.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to determine the energy of an accoustic wave field other than by using Poynting vectors.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

I appreciate any help - thanks!

**EDIT:**
Is there a counterpart to the elastic energy density foracoustic media which does not involve the medium density $\rho$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy flux of an acoustic wave is 
$$
\vec J = \vec v p \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1)
$$

The relevant energy density to be used in these calculation is actually $p+1/2 \rho v^2$, but since we are discussing a small amplitude wave (= no shock wave), $v$ is an infinitesimal quantity; thus $1/2\rho v^2$ is lower order than $p$ (second vs. first), thus it can be neglected.

You should also keep in mind that eq. (1) applies instantaneously, while you will most likely want a value averaged over a period. If you write $p = p_0 +\delta\!p$, you find
$$
<\vec J> = <\vec v p > = <\vec v p_0> + <\vec v \delta\!p>
$$
where $<>$ symbolize averages over a period. The first term on the RHS obviously vanishes, so you are left with
$$
<\vec J> = <\vec v \delta\!p>
$$
The RHS can easily be average using expressions from elementary textbooks.

A reasonable comment is that an expansion to first order in the wave amplitude has given rise to second-order energy flux and density.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @Marius ! Am I right, that the counterpart of the _elastic energy density_ $E = K + W = \frac{1}{2} \tau_{ij} \epsilon_{ij} + \frac{1}{2} \rho \dot{u_i} \dot{u_i}$ is the _sound energy density_ with $\vec{E} = \frac{\vec{J}}{c} = \frac{P \vec{v}}{c}$ where $P$ is pressure, $v$ is the particle velocity and $c$ is the medium velocity?

Comment: @MichaelScott Yes and no: the analogue of the elastic energy density must be a scalar because it is not a flux, and must be quadratic in the small deviations. So you may use $<\delta\!v^2> \rho$ or, which is the same, $<\delta\!p^2>/(c^2\rho)$.

Comment: is there a way to reformulate this without using $\rho$ ? I am asking since my issue has it's origins in seismics where I use constant density wave propagators...

Comment: @MichaelScott Not sure I follow: the $\rho$ in the previous formulae is the unperturbed density. Where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, that I assume constant density for my (solid) medium where the impedance contrasts are defined by different medium velocities $c$. Since the energy assessment with **Poynting vectors** does not need density contrasts but only pressures of the field, I need a formulation for the acoustic energy density without the medium density $\rho$ in order to compare the wavefield energy. **Poynting vectors** vs. **acoustic energy density**.

Comment: @MichaelScott like I said, the density in the formulae above is the unperturbed density, thus it is a constant.

Comment: ok. but I cannot simply set $\rho$ to a specific constant since the energies would not be comparable anymore, right? I mean there is a difference when setting $\rho = 1$ or $\rho = 3000$ ?

Comment: edit: Isn't the absolute value of $\vec{E} = \frac{J}{c}$ an analouge to the absolute value of the Poynting vector $\vec{S}$ ?

Comment: @MichaelScott Yes it is. Not the same as the energy density, though

Comment: thanks a lot. just to get this clear: $|\vec{S}| = |-\dot{p} \nabla p| \hat{=} |\vec{E}| = |\frac{\vec{J}}{c}| = |\frac{p \vec{v}}{c}|$ ??

Comment: @MichaelScott Yes, it's ok