# Poynting vector of a scalar wave

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

Consider a scalar wave (of sound for example) of the form $\psi(\vec{r},t)$. Which is its Poynting vector? I mean, the vector that takes account for the energy flux in the same sense as for the case of an electromagnetic wave.

Comment: Similar question: [Energy estimation of an acoustic wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131137/energy-estimation-of-an-acoustic-wave)

Answer (score 4):

As a fast answer I would point out that the Poynting vector is just the spatio-temporal components of the electromagnetic [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Definition). So for a scalar wave, or in general for a scalar field, $\phi$ , you would like to search there. For example, the energy-momentum tensor for the real [Klein-Gordon field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) is:

\begin{equation}
\Theta_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi - \frac{1}{2} \eta_{\mu \nu} \left( \partial^\sigma \phi \partial_\sigma \phi + m^2 \phi^2\right)
\end{equation}
where $\partial_\mu = \partial / \partial x^\mu$, $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, is the [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Minkowski_metric) and $m$ is the mass of the field. The spatio-temporal components of this tensor are just (the dot denoting temporal derivative, and latin subscripts spatial components):
\begin{equation}
\Theta_{0 i} = \partial_0 \phi \partial_i \phi = \dot{\phi}\partial_i\phi
\end{equation}
which is just the fields linear momentum density $\mathcal{P}_i = \Theta_{0i}$, as in the electromagnetic case:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{P}_i^{EM} = \frac{S_i}{c^2} =-\frac{T_{0i}}{c}
\end{equation}
(maybe wihtout the minus sign), here $S_i$ is the Poynting vector and $T_{0i}$ the spatio-temporal components of the electromagnetic energy-momentum (or stress-energy) tensor.

Hope I clarified some ideas!

kl0z.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with the 1 dimensional case and generalize to n dimensions afterwards.

For an idealized string the wave equation is,

$$\rho \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} = T \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}$$

With $\rho$ being it's linear density and T being it's tension. We can use the relation $v^2 = \frac{T}{\rho}$ to convert it into standard form but this form will be more convenient for us.

We can use physical intuition to guess the form of the kinetic and potential energy densities and verify mathematically that the total energy is conserved within the bulk of our region of consideration.

In each small segment $\Delta x$ of the string there is a mass $m = \rho \Delta x$, moving at velocity $v = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$, its' kinetic energy is then,

$$K = \frac{mv^2}{2} = \frac{\rho}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]^2 \Delta x$$

Our kinetic energy density is then,

$$\kappa = \frac{K}{\Delta x} = \frac{\rho}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]^2$$

In each each small segment of the string $\Delta x$ we have the equivalent of a vertical spring with spring constant $k = \frac{T}{\Delta x}$ stretched out by a distance $d = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \Delta x$ vertically. It's potential energy is then,

$$P = \frac{kd^2}{2} = \frac{T}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right]^2 \Delta x$$

Our potential energy density is then,

$$p = \frac{P}{\Delta x} = \frac{T}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right]^2$$

The total energy density is then,

$$\mu = \kappa + p = \frac{\rho}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]^2 + \frac{T}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right]^2$$

The total energy contained within a region $[0, L]$ of the string would be,

$$E = \int_0^L{\mu dx}$$

The energy flux entering this region should be,

$$\Phi = \frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^L{\mu dx}$$

Using the Leibniz rule,

$$=\int_0^L{\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t}dx}$$

Evaluating $\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t}$,

$$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[ 
\frac{\rho}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]^2 + \frac{T}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right]^2 \right] = \rho \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} + T \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t \partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$$

Using the wave equation to substitute for the second temporal derivative in the first term,

$$= T \left[\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t \partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right]$$

Which we can see is a spatial derivative of $T \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$,

$$= T \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]$$

Plugging this back into our flux integral,

$$\Phi = T \int_0^L{\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]dx} = T \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right] \Big|_{x=0}^{x=L}$$

Here we've verified that our expression for energy is conserved within the length of the string and can only flow into or out of the string through the boundaries. We can also see that it does not flow through fixed boundaries, i.e. $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = 0$, or through free boundaries, i.e. $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} = 0$. We can identify the quantity,

$$S = -T \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$$

as the energy flux flowing from left to right on the string, the equivalent of the Poynting vector for the 1D string. Interestingly it does not depend on the linear density $\rho$ of the string, but this makes sense when you consider that each little section of the string is modelled as moving purely vertically, it can't transfer it's kinetic energy into a region by moving horizontally across the boundary, it can only transfer energy to it's neighbors by tugging on the little "spring" which connects them, hence why the tension is the only relevant constant.

Generalization to n dimensions is fairly straight forward, we can roughly summarize the process as replacing the spatial derivative with the gradient.

Wave equation:

$$\rho \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} = T \nabla^2 \psi$$

Kinetic energy density:

$$\kappa = \frac{\rho}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]^2$$

Potential energy density:

$$p = \frac{T}{2} [\nabla \psi] \cdot [\nabla \psi]$$

Total energy density:

$$\mu = \kappa + p = \frac{\rho}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]^2 + \frac{T}{2} [\nabla \psi] \cdot [\nabla \psi]$$

Energy within a fixed region $\Sigma$:

$$E = \int_{\Sigma}{\mu dV}$$

Energy flux entering the region(supposedly, at this point):

$$\Phi = \frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Sigma}{\mu dV}$$

Leibniz rule, assuming the region is fixed:

$$= \int_{\Sigma}{\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t}dV}$$

Evaluating $\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t}$,

$$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[ 
\frac{\rho}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right]^2 + \frac{T}{2} \left[ \nabla\psi \right] \cdot \left[ \nabla\psi \right] \right] = \rho \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial t^2} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} + T \left[ \nabla \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right] \cdot \left[ \nabla \psi \right]$$

Substituting using the wave equation,

$$= T \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \nabla^2 \psi + \left[ \nabla \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right] \cdot \left[ \nabla \psi \right] \right]$$

Which we recognize as a divergence,

$$= T\nabla \cdot \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \nabla \psi \right]$$

Plugging this back into the flux integral and using the divergence theorem,

$$\Phi = T \int_{\Sigma}{\nabla \cdot \left[ \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \nabla \psi \right] dV} = T \oint_{\partial \Sigma}{\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \nabla \psi \cdot dA}$$

Where $\partial \Sigma$ is the boundary of $\Sigma$ and dA points outwards.

Here we again verify that our expression for energy is conserved within the bulk of the region, and that energy flows into or out of the region only through the boundary. We can identify the quantity,

$$S = -T \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \nabla \psi$$

as the energy flux density, the equivalent of the Poynting vector for a scalar wave in n dimensions.