# How to understand power propagation speed?

Tags: waves, acoustics, power, speed

When reading papers, I am confused with power propagation speed of acoustic wave in fluid. The problem is given below.

For a plane, acoustic wave with pressure

$p_i(x,y,t)=Ae^{j(\omega t-kx\sin\theta+ky\cos\theta)}$

incidenting on a fully reflecting planar surface, the total acoustic pressure (incident+reflected) is given by

$p(x,y,t)=2A\cos(ky\cos\theta)e^{j(\omega t-kx\sin\theta)}$.

where $k$ is the wavenumber and $\theta$ is the incident angle.

The above configuration is given by the figure

[image]

In the figure, there're three speeds:

1. The sound speed $c$, which describes the reaction of a volume of fluid to deformation.
2. The phase speed $c_p=c/\sin\theta$, which describes the propagating speed of wavefront (constant pressure phase planes).
3. The power propagation speed in the x direction $c_e=c\sin\theta$, which describes the propagation of acoustic power.

The first two speeds have clearly definitions and can be calculated using explicit formulae. For example, the phase speed can be obtained by solving the total derivative of the phase of total acoustic pressure,

$d(\omega t-kx\sin\theta))$

When it comes to the power propagation speed, I could not understand what it true means and how to relate it to the expression $c_e=c\sin\theta$.

1. How to know power is propagated? Can we say the power is propagating from position A to position B when the deformation transfers from A to B?
2. How to calculate the power propagation speed? I have tried to write the expression for the total power (potential+kinetic) and find the total derivative of its phase, just as what is done to find the phase speed. But the result is $c/\sin\theta$, instead of $c\sin\theta$ that is given by the figure.

Hope you can help, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Energy estimation of an acoustic wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131137/)

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Thanks for the link. But the post you give only answers how to calculate acoustic energy. But what I want to know is how acoustic energy propagates.

Comment: It's partly given in that question already - calculate Poynting vector, it's the energy/power propagation direction. You can also check this article "[A Study on the Scattering Energy Properties of an Elastic Spherical Shell in Sandy Sediment Usingan Improved Energy Method](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313687114_A_Study_on_the_Scattering_Energy_Properties_of_an_Elastic_Spherical_Shell_in_Sandy_Sediment_Using_an_Improved_Energy_Method)".